# How to fetch second level of categories in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i want to fetch records from categories table for second level. See my category table below:-

```
id  name     parent_id
 1   Women     ROOT
 2   Dress       1
 3   Denim       1
 4   Sweaters    1
 5   Long Dress  2
 6   Short Dress 2
```

I have tried the below code:-

```
SELECT categories.id,categories.name,categories.parent_id FROM `categories`
join categories c
on c.id = categories.parent_id
```

My expected output is like:-

```
id  name     parent_id
 2   Dress       1
 3   Denim       1
 4   Sweaters    1
```

I want to fetch records of second level means the where parent id is ROOT and their category id is linked with parent_id. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try a single level self join, with the condition that the left side is the `ROOT` position:

```
SELECT c2.id, c2.name, c2.parent_id
FROM categories c1
INNER JOIN categories c2
    ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
WHERE
    c1.parent_id = 'ROOT';
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

you could use in

```
select * from category where parent_id in (
select id from category where parent_id='ROOT'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select b.id,b.name,b.parent_id from categories a,categories b 
where a.id=b.parent_id and a.parent_id='ROOT';
```

Comment: Minus upvote for me.. do you think its dyanmic for 1k categories

Comment: @kunal dynamic for 1k categories what do you mean it will work i  reckon!!!!!!!!!1

Comment: why you give statically parent_id= 1

Comment: @kunal it is same as Tim Biegeleisen's answer which you ticked only syntax is different!!!!!!!!!!